How do I modify the item count of an unstackable item?
I need to change the count of an unstackable item entity (e.g., a shulker box). This used to work in pre-1.20.5, but with the changes in stacking, it does not work now.
I am trying to regain the same behavior, so the items cannot be stacked after being unstacked.
execute at @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{count:1}}] if block ~ ~-1.5 ~ hopper run data modify entity @e[type=item,distance=..1,limit=1] Item.count set value 2


You need to use components to modify the stack limit and probably for other things as well. I would recommend watching Slicedlime's 1.20.5 technical news video, but it is not released yet. :D

@FabianRöling I tried that and it kind of, but it doesn't recreate the same behavior as it did pre-1.20.5

I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is with NBT editors like NBTexplorer or mods. But if you don't need them to be useable, you can use bundles by activating the experiment in the world creation or saving a bundle in a hotbar slot.

By the saving the hotbar slot i mean the default like {C+[a number]}
